# Schedule the same task for 500 times

Tags: java, multithreading, scheduler

I have a task that I want to run 500 times in parallel, if I want to run it only once I would do something like this

```
Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor().scheduleWithFixedDelay(
            taskProvider.get(),
            0,
            100,
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS
        );
```

I want to run 500 tasks(high IO) that I get from the task provider in parallel with fixed rate, is there a way to do this without creating 500 executors or submitting 500 tasks in a while loop?

EDIT: I know I can create a thread pool of size 500, if I do that I will have to submit 500 tasks(?) to run them in parallel, I was looking if there is a way to do it without submitting the similar tasks since basically they have the same content, I also don't want to start all of them at the same time, I want to start 50 every 100ms.

Comment: What's the point?

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? For a parallelism level of 500 you'll need either 500 threads (like an executor with a core size of 500) or a different approach such as the [Reactor pattern](https://dzone.com/articles/understanding-reactor-pattern-thread-based-and-eve). What do those tasks do?

Comment: you can submit single task which resubmits itself 500 times. Or you can submit 50 tasks each of which resubmits itself 10 times. Just add to the end of task: `if (counter++<10) executor.submit(this);`

Comment: i'm not sure what you are looking for but you can define a pool of a fixed number of thread and give them 500 tasks with ThreadPoolExecutor. You can find a exemple [here](https://www.journaldev.com/1069/threadpoolexecutor-java-thread-pool-example-executorservice). 
You will define a number of thread "alive" and when one of them become free the ThreadPoolExecutor will give him another task.

Comment: if I create a pool with size 500, and submit a single task, will it be scheduled to run 500 times ?

Comment: @MauricePerry I'm doing an experiement where I'm trying to simulate writing to another service by concurrent threads at fixed rate, the closest thing I can think of what I'm trying to do is a load test, but I'm also monitoring the behavior of the other service

Comment: @Shadi OK, but what's wrong with a loop?

Comment: @MauricePerry I updated the original comment, I also don't want to start them at the same time, I want to start 50 tasks every 100ms

Comment: @Shadi you can supply an initial delay when you schedule your task

Comment: Why don't you just use a load tester then? Considering how new you seem to be to working with executors and concurrency, you should not be trying to do this in code. You could use for example JMeter and configure all that boilerplate from the GUI.

Comment: @Kayaman the requests are not http requests

Comment: JMeter isn't limited to HTTP.

Comment: We already evaluated JMeter and its not applicable to our use case, mainly because the results of each task might send another request to another service and we are interested in the whole lifespan of both requests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to do this manually:

```
void submitTaskChunks(int chunkCount, int chunkSize, long delayMillis) throws InterruptedException {
    ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

    for (int i = 0; i < chunkCount; i++) {
        List<Callable<Void>> taskChunk = IntStream.range(0, chunkSize)
                .mapToObj(k -> taskProvider.get())
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        executorService.invokeAll(taskChunk);
        Thread.sleep(delayMillis);
    }

    executorService.shutdown();
    executorService.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
}
```

To submit 50 tasks every 100 ms 10 times:
`submitTaskChunks(10, 50, 100);`
Note that taskProvider.get should return `Callable<Void>`.

Comment: Thanks, this is similar to what I want but I'll be using scheduledExecutor

Answer (score 0):

You can create list of tasks of size 500 and use

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(500);
executor.invokeAll(tasks);
```